# What does "RlpInvalidIndirection" error mean?

Tags: parity, rpc, rlp

I run my own Parity node for Ropsten network.

I am sending raw transactions to the node with "eth_sendRawTransaction" api, and sometimes it returns `{-32602, "Invalid RLP.", "RlpInvalidIndirection"}` message. It occurs occasionally(once in 20 times? approximately).

As I googled, I get to the parity source code page([link](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/9e719f088f37ec9af7a24403cbd7e8cbfd9a134e/util/rlp/src/error.rs#L30)). However, I can't get more useful information about it. There's just a comment below on it.

`/// Non-canonical (longer than necessary) representation used for data or list.`.

Since most of times it succeeds, it doesn't make sense for me. Lengths of all the messages are same.

**What does that message generally mean?**

I am sorry that I can't attach the full source code of mine because of a personal reason.